# Azure DevOps 2019- Code search plugin/extension is not getting installed

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

We are using Azure DevOps Server 2019 (On prem).
We tried installing 'code search' plugin setup manually instead of installing from marketplace as per our organization policy. We are getting mentioned error during installation.

Please suggest the way forward. Are there any prerequisites for this plugin installation?

[image]

when we tried directly from market place, its getting installed without error. But it is recommendation for our organization to install individual setup.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure DevOps Server, you may install search service:

1. On the same server: [Install and configure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/install-configure-search?view=azure-devops)
2. On a separate server: [Install Azure DevOps Server Search Service on a separate server](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2021/04/12/install-azure-devops-server-search-service-on-a-separate-server/)